# Excel VBA Macro: Creating a Macro That Extracts Duplicate Record and Pastes into New Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to create a simple macro that takes all duplicate records from a source sheet and pastes them into a new sheet.

I have been messing around, and the closest I've gotten is the creation of a list that extracts all duplicate values except for the first duplicate value in a cluster.
So for example, if a list looks like this below:
1
1
2
3
4
5
1

The sheet with the duplicates will list:
1
1

It will consider the first instance of '1' as unique, and that is totally not what I want. I want it to show every single instance of the duplicated row, so I awnt this:
1
1
1

Comment: @Christian Payne answer is excellent. But if you really need a macro you could do something similar to [that 'alternative' solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15877730/2143262) but you need to reverse it- there I removed all duplicated items and you need to keep them. Therefore, instead of removing you will paste them to sheet.

Comment: Iterate over cells containing the list, add uniques to a Collection or Scripting Dictionary, storing the item and its # of occurrences. Then iterate over the items and do a loop to print out the # of occurrences sequentially on the next sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do to deal with duplicates.  It isn't a macro, but works for me:

1. Sort the column with the duplicate.  (For this example, say column C)
2. In a new column, write an IF function.  Eg in cell D5:  =if(c5=c4,1,"")
3. Copy cell D5 to the entire list.
4. Copy and *[paste value](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/copy-cell-values-not-formulas-HA010244903.aspx)* column D over itself.  Eg in step 2, the formula is replaced with a "1"
5. Sort column D
6. Any row with a 1 is a duplicate.  Do as you wish!

You can also do things like find the sum of column D (shows me how many duplicates)

Comment: Hi Christian, I currently run a similar process and work on a team that has to run it on thousands of records. Sometimes it becomes resource-intensive, and it is because of that I am looking for a macro. I really appreciate it though!

Answer (score 0):

**After clarifications by OP the following procedure will perform as required:**

```
Sub CopyDuplicates()
'***************************************************************
'** This proc expects you to select all the cells in a single **
'** column that you want to check for duplicates in. If dup-  **
'** licates are found, the entire row will be copied to the   **
'** predetermined sheet.                                      **
'***************************************************************

Dim ShO As Worksheet
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim pRow As Integer
Dim c As Range, cTmp As Range
Dim found
Dim Addresses() As String
Dim a() As String
Dim p2 As Integer
Dim tfFlag As Boolean, sTmp As Variant

Set ShO = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'You can change this to whatever worksheet name you want the duplicates in
Set Rng1 = Application.Selection 'Rng1 is all the currently selected cells
pRow = 1 'This is the first row in our outpur sheet that will be used to record duplicates
ReDim a(0) 'Initialize our array that holds found values

For Each c In Rng1.Cells 'Cycle through each cell in our selected range
ReDim Addresses(0) 'This array holds the cell address for our duplicates.
                   'We will reset the array each time we move to the next cell

'Now check the array of already found duplicates.
'If the current value is already there skip to next value
tfFlag = False
For Each sTmp In a
    If CStr(c.Value) = sTmp Or CStr(c.Value) = "xXDeleteXx" Then 'We've already done this value, move on
        tfFlag = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

    If Not tfFlag Then 'Remember the flag is true when we have already located the
                       'duplicates for this value, so skip to next value
        With Rng1
            Set found = .Find(c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues) 'Search entire selected range for value
            If Not found Is Nothing Then 'Found it
                Addresses(0) = found.Address 'Record the address we found it
                Do 'Now keep finding occurances of it
                    Set found = .FindNext(found)
                    If found.Address <> Addresses(0) Then
                        ReDim Preserve Addresses(UBound(Addresses) + 1)
                        Addresses(UBound(Addresses)) = found.Address
                    End If
                Loop While Not found Is Nothing And found.Address <> Addresses(0) 'Until we get back to the original address

                If UBound(Addresses) > 0 Then 'We Found Duplicates
                    a(UBound(a)) = c.Value 'Record the value we found a duplicate for in an array
                    ReDim Preserve a(UBound(a) + 1) 'add an empty spot to the array for next value

                    ShO.Range("A" & pRow).Value = "Duplicate Rows for Value " & c.Value & _
                              " in Column " & c.Column & " on original sheet" 'Add a label row
                    pRow = pRow + 1 'Increment to the next row
                    For p2 = UBound(Addresses) To 0 Step -1 'Cycle through the duplicate addresses
                        Set cTmp = Rng1.Worksheet.Range(Addresses(p2)) 'we just want to easily get the correct row to copy
                        Rng1.Worksheet.Rows(cTmp.Row).Copy ShO.Rows(pRow) 'Copy form orig to duplicates sheet
                            cTmp.Value = "xXDeleteXx" 'Mark for Delete the original row
                        pRow = pRow + 1 'Increment row counter
                    Next p2
                    pRow = pRow + 1 'This increment will give us a blank row between sets of dupicates
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next
'Now go delete all the marked rows

Do
tfFlag = False
For Each c In Rng1
    If c.Value = "xXDeleteXx" Then
        Rng1.Worksheet.Rows(c.Row).Delete (xlShiftUp)
        tfFlag = True
    End If
Next
Loop Until tfFlag = False

End
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Kaciree,Thanks for the response. I tested the macro and Sheet two populates like this: 1 $A$2 $A$3 $A$4 $A$5 $A$6 $A$1 
. I actually want it to literally extract and paste the rows into the sheet, rather than provide the referential cell points in which the duplicates lie. How can the code be edited to make that happen? Is that even possible?

Comment: Yes we can do that. Do you want to find duplicates in a single column, then move the whole row? Or find only whole rows which are duplicates? Do we want to copy the duplicate rows, or 'move' them? Should each set of duplicates be added to its own separate sheet?

Comment: Hi Kaciree, I would want to find duplicates in a single column and then move the whole row. :D. Thanks

Comment: @user1599325 ok so the CopyDuplicates proc I posted should do what you want. I use 'selected' to choose the range to search, which you may want to modify for your specific application.

Comment: @user1599325 to clarify, when you move the duplicates you want to keep the first occurrence of the duplicate in the original sheet or move it as well?

Comment: Hi Kaciree, I do not want to keep the first occurrence of the dupe. I want to remove them all and put them in a asheet. I believe this works though.

Comment: Hi Kaciree,Did your update change anything? I am trying to run the updated Proc and it is not pasting any of the duplicate rows :(

Comment: @user1599325 ok sorry, I had to tweak it. Please test now

Comment: Hi Kaciree, Out of curiosity, what did you tweak to fix the proc?