# FILTER Function for integers - VBA

Tags: vba

I searched the website but was not succesfful and tried doing some research on this but facing with " Type Mismatch" error.

I declared an array as integer type but the FILTER function seems to work only with STRING's. Can you please let me know how I can use the FILTER function for integers?

`If UBound(Filter(CntArr(), count)) > 0 Then
          msgbox "found"`

End If

Comment: answering your question- yes, it works with `Integers` but it treats figures like `Strings`. Moreover, when calling Filter function do it this way: `...Filter(CntArr,count)...`. Check also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15877730/2143262) to understand risks of using `Filter` function...

Answer (score 1):

as i understand you need to know if specified count present in array. You can use `for loop` for it:

```
Dim found as Boolean
found = False
For i = 0 To UBound (CntArr())
   If CntArr(i) = count Then
      found = True
      Exit For
   End If
Next i
If found Then msgbox "found" End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Below I have created IsIntegerInArray() function that returns boolean. Follow the two Subs for an example of integer array declaration. Declaring array as Integer should also prevent some unnecessary bugs caused by implicit data conversion.

```
Sub test_int_array()
    Dim a() As Integer

    ReDim a(3)
    a(0) = 2
    a(1) = 15
    a(2) = 16
    a(3) = 8

    '''   expected result: 1 row for each integer in the array
    Call test_printing_array(a)
End Sub

Sub test_printing_array(arr() As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 20
        If IsIntegerInArray(i, arr) Then
            Debug.Print i & " is in array."
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Function IsIntegerInArray(integerToBeFound As Integer, arr() As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer

    '''   incorrect approach:
    '''   IsIntegerInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, integerToBeFound)) > -1)   ' this approach searches for string, e.g. it matches "1" in "12"

    '''   correct approach:
    IsIntegerInArray = False
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) = integerToBeFound Then
            IsIntegerInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: I do not know VB, but there is no obvious setting of `IsIntegerInArray = False` for when the number is not found. Can you please [edit] the answer to explain how `False` is returned.

Comment: The trick is that boolean datatype has default value False, so there is no need to assign it explicitly. However I updated the response to make it clear.
Also note that VB and VBA are different languages (with common ancestor maybe).