# Removing repeated array items - VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, repeat

I have a question in Excel VBA:

Lets say I have an array made of: {a,b,c,d,a,a,b,e,f,d,c,e,g,f,e}, where some elements are repeated.

I would like to obtain the list of all elements without the repetition one: i.e. {a,b,c,d,e,f,g}

I have found a code that removes the duplicate elements ([VBA Removing duplicates values in an array including the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877273/vba-removing-duplicates-values-in-an-array-including-the-same-value)), but then I obtain {g} because it is the only one not repeated.

I would appreciate any hint tips or help!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: use a dictionary or collection is the fastest way (least code). Many answers here use that method

Comment: Thanks I will look into that! Can the disctionary deal with lots of items? My initial array has more than 10000 rows.

Comment: Brilliant both methods work perfectly fine! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already looked at it for you. In the first example, the collection will contain only the unique items. You can loop over the collection to get access to them. In the second example I use a dictionary - and you can get the unique items a little more easily.

Here you are:

```
Sub arr_parse_test()


Dim rra As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim Dict As New Collection


rra = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "g", "a", "b", "z")
On Error Resume Next
For i = 0 To UBound(rra)
    Dict.Add rra(i), CStr(rra(i))
    If (Err.Number <> 0) Then Err.Clear
Next i

End Sub
```

For completeness here is an example using the `scripting.dictionary`. It is often preferred over VBA Collection. It is easier to recover the unique items, as a bonus. Your unique items are chucked into the variant/array `rra2`. Check it out

```
Sub arr_parse_test2()


Dim rra, rra2 As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim Dict As Object

Set Dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

rra = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "g", "a", "b", "z")

For i = 0 To UBound(rra)
    If (Not Dict.exists(CStr(rra(i)))) Then Dict.Add CStr(rra(i)), rra(i)
Next i

rra2 = Dict.Items

End Sub
```

It works because VBA collections and MS (scripting) dictionaries only admit items with *unique* keys. Collections will error out if you try to add an item with a key that already exists in the collection. Hence the `on error resume next` statement.

With a dictionary, you can test if a key already exists (using `Dict.Exists`) in the dictionary, before adding. You can learn more about collections and dictionaries from [here](https://sites.google.com/site/beyondexcel/project-updates/datadictionaryinvba-completesyntaxdocumentation) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187234).

Comment: You can use Dict.exists(key) to check if the key exists before trying to add.

Comment: @PaulKelly yes - true that. Just mashed the previous collection example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Collection or Dictionary for this.

Check this piece of code:

```
Option Base 1
Sub unique()
Dim arr As New Collection, a
Dim aFirstArray() As Variant
Dim i As Long

aFirstArray() = Array("a","b","c","d","a","a","b","e","f","d","c","e","g","f","e")

On Error Resume Next
For Each a In aFirstArray
arr.Add a, a
Next

For i = 1 To arr.Count
Cells(i, 1) = arr(i)
Next

End Sub
```

In the first row of excel, you can check you will have list of unique records.