# VBA (Microsoft Access) Function to delete duplicates in Array

Tags: arrays, vba

I need a function which will delete duplicate elements in an array in VBA, I have searched for this but none of the given functions worked for me, they always give some kind of error. So lets say I have an array of strings:

```
Dim strArray() As String
strArray = Split("word1, word2, word3, word1, word2, word4", ",")
```

I need a function which will return another "filtered array" which will contain no duplicates so it will contain "word1, word2, word3, word4" Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15877730/1519058 ?!

Comment: that code gives me "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Comment: @Markazol, did you try my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Function FilterWords(words() As String) As String()
    Dim word As Variant
    Dim newWords As String

    For Each word In words
        If InStr(newWords, word) = 0 Then newWords = newWords & word & ","
    Next word
    FilterWords = Split(Left(newWords, Len(newWords) - 1), ",")
End Function
```

to be used like

```
Sub main()    
    Dim strArray() As String, strFilteredArray() As String

    strArray = Split("word1,word2,word3,word1,word2,word4", ",")        
    strFilteredArray = FilterWords(strArray) 
End Sub
```