# Removing duplicates in comma separated string in every cell of a column in MS Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am building an Access database which imports data from an Excel file. Unfortunately, one field which is imported, contains multiple IP addresses with duplicates separated by a comma. **I want to remove the duplicates from that string,** so I can separate them afterwards and paste individually in a column with only the distinct IP addresses remaining.
My table looks something like this:

```
Host_name | IP Address 
----------------------
mba234    192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.3
mba678    158.234.12.4, 123.123.123.23, 158.234.12.4, 123.123.123.23, 156.234.567.12
etc.
```

And in the end it should look like this:

```
Host name | IP Address 
----------------------
mba234    192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.3
mba678    158.234.12.4, 123.123.123.23, 156.234.567.12
etc.
```

As the length of the column varies for each import, I need a solution for the entire column: IP Address. So far I only found solutions for an individual cell or a predefined array of cells but not for an entire column with random amount of rows...

Can you help me out?

Comment: You'll need to do this in VBA.

Comment: Use `Split()` to create an array of the IP's based on the comma delimiter, and then parse the array using a dictionary object to create a unique list, then re-build the string using the dictionary.

Comment: Why not normalize the data and put the IPs into an own table? Else you will have a hard time finding the host of a specific IP?

Comment: VBA (Microsoft Access) Function to delete duplicates in Array https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561861/vba-microsoft-access-function-to-delete-duplicates-in-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA (Microsoft Access) Function to delete duplicates in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561861/vba-microsoft-access-function-to-delete-duplicates-in-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could do it the 'hard' way.

- You need an external program called `awk.exe`,
- This macro will convert the input string.

  ```
  Function ReturnUnique(field As String) As String
    Dim Linetext As String
    Dim s As String
    Dim f As Integer
    Dim cmd As String
    cmd = "cmd /c echo " + field + " | awk -F ', ' '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { a[$i]=$i }; for (i in a) { print a[i] }}' >d:\temp\temp.txt"
    cmd = Replace(cmd, "'", """")
    Shell cmd, vbMinimizedFocus
    f = FreeFile()
    Open "d:\temp\temp.txt" For Input As #f
    Do While Not (EOF(f))
      Line Input #f, Linetext
      s = s + Linetext
    Loop
    ReturnUnique = s
  End Function
  Sub test()
    Dim t As String
    t = ReturnUnique("192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.3")
    Debug.Print t
  End Sub
  ```

example (that's why the `test()` is there!):

```
test
192.168.1.3 192.168.1.1
```

Now you can call tis function for every record in your table.....

A Windows version of `awk` can be found here: https://www.klabaster.com/progs/gawk4.zip

Answer (score 0):

I think string split is your best option.

You can find an example [here](https://www.devhut.net/2018/04/22/access-using-split-in-a-query/).

In your case, it appears that your delimiter isn't just a comma: ","
Instead, it is ", ".

This should easily allow you to turn your example into this, and consolidate more as needed:

```
Host_name   IP_Address  Run_Count
------------------------------
mba234  192.168.1.1 1
mba234  192.168.1.1 2
mba234  192.168.1.3 1
mba678  158.234.12.4    1
mba678  123.123.123.23  1
mba678  158.234.12.4    2
mba678  123.123.123.23  2
mba678  156.234.567.12  1
```